# Visual studio: Copying content during build

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I need to copy test files after build if they were changed. Here i found the solution:

```
<Target Name="CopyContent" AfterTargets="Build">
  <ItemGroup>
    <DeployFileGroup 
      Include="**\*.json;**\*.png;**\*.wav;**\*.mp3;" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(DeployFileGroup)" 
    DestinationFiles="@(DeployFileGroup->'$(TargetDir)%(RecursiveDir)\%(Filename)%    (Extension)')" 
    SkipUnchangedFiles="True" UseHardlinksIfPossible="True"/>
</Target>
```

But it works only if I run msbuild from the command line. How can I force vs to check for content file changes?